# Is there a way to tokenize a string with sscanf if we don't know the size of the string and can't dynamically allocate memory?

Tags: c, syntax

Is there a way to tokenize a string with sscanf if we don't know the size of the string and can't dynamically allocate memory?

Here is an example that doesn't answer the above requirements:

```
char token[100];///we can't do that in this case since we don't know the size of the string
int offset = 0;
int consumed = 0;

sscanf(format + offset, "%s%n", tokenf, &consumed);
offset += consumed;
```

Note: I'm aware of `strtok`, `strtok_r` and `strtok_s` but I'm asking about `sscanf` or another way.

Also, are the `strtok` functions dynamically allocate memory for the tokens?

Comment: `char token[100];` is not dynamic allocation.

Comment: Yes but we can't assume the size of the string since the size is unknown. @milleniumbug

Comment: In that case this is impossible - either you use dynamic allocation, or you have to assume a maximum size.

Comment: That's what I thought but I hoped I was wrong. so I have to use the `strtok` functions. Thanks @milleniumbug

Comment: Consider adding more details to your question. At this moment it is very unclear what you're trying to do.

Comment: Also, you know the maximum size of your token - it's not larger than whatever `format` is.

Comment: Just trying tokenize a string of unknown size without dynamic allocation. It's supposed to be an exercise for the `printf`, `sscanf`, `sprintf`,`scanf` functions. @milleniumbug

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72523/discussion-between-milleniumbug-and-kuhaku).

Comment: `strtok` does not dynamically allocate memory. It writes null bytes into the string you're tokenizing; and uses a static pointer inside the C library to track the current string being tokenized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using GNU libc (or a recent POSIX version), you can use the `m` modifier to scanf to get it to allocate memory for you:

```
char *token;
int offset = 0;
int consumed = 0;

if (sscanf(format + offset "%ms%n", &token, &consumed) >= 1) {
    offset += consumed;
    ... do something with token ...
    free(token);
}
```

However, this is a GNU extension (and is also part of POSIX-2008 so may be at least somewhat portable), so may not work everywhere.  Also, do always be sure to check the return value from `sscanf`...

Comment: `m` is the modifier, `s` is the format specifier -- `s` means scan a whitespace delimiter string of non-whitespace characters, `m` mean allocate memory for the scanned string and store it in the pointed at pointer.  `m` can be used with the format specifiers `%s` `%[` or `%c`.  Not part of C99.  Maybe C18?